# Display WP-Types custom fields in post

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooCommerce website where on products I added some custom fields using WP-Types plugin. The website has a section "News", which basically is a blog.

How can I insert wanted products into a blog post by including its custom fields that I added with WP-Types plugin?

Is it possible to create a custom shortcode for that (more or less a shortcode that accepts parameters as product ID and that contains shortcodes for the custom fields)? Or maybe there is an option to take values of the fields via PHP code in the product template code, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may or may not know any post meta data is stored in a new table, $wpdb->postmeta. This table has four fields:

- 'meta_id' - A unique id for each entry.
- 'post_id' - The ID of the post for this metadata.
- 'meta_key' - The name of the 'key'.
- 'meta_value' - The value associated with the key.

To use metadata in your theme use the [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) function.

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

How that works is:

1. $post_id is the ID of the post you want the meta values for. Use $post->ID to get a post's ID within the $post variable scope. Use get_the_ID() to retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.
2. $key is a string containing the name of the meta value you want.
3. $single can either be true or false. If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields.

And to use that in a shortcode add this to your child themes functions.php:

```
function your_function_name( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'key' => '',
        'single' => 'true',
    ), $atts );

    return get_post_meta($a['id'], $a['key'], $a['single']);
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_text', 'your_function_name' );
```

The above function would create this shortcode: `[shortcode_text id="" key="" single=""]`.

As I said before if you want to retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop leave out `id=""` altogether as I set the default value to be `get_the_ID()`.
And if you only want to get a single value you can leave out `single=""` as well as the default is set to true.

### [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

### [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: This refers to metadata of post. I need to retrieve values of custom fields of a WooCommerce product that I insert in my post.

Comment: All meta is in the same table

Comment: Sorry - my bad, I thought post and product use different functions, tables and etc. - I am fresh to woocommerce and get_POST_meta got me confused. I modified the code you provided according to my needs and got everything I needed, so thank you very much, I am marking this as a correct answer, because it is. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great :) glad it worked for you!